# Perform calculation based on filter within dataframe using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe where I would like to only perform a specific calculation based on if a column value is true. (Else perform a calculation if column is not true)

**Data**

```
ID     USED AVAIL   TOTAL   stat    Ready
Box1    5   5       10      yes     TRUE
Box1    40  10      50      no      FALSE
Box2    15  5       20      maybe   TRUE
Box2    10  50      60      yes     TRUE
Box2    10  20      30      no      FALSE
```

**Desired**

using formula:

```
IF ['READY'] = TRUE,  THEN SUM(used * 0.5)+(used*1)
IF ['READY'] = FALSE, THEN SUM(used * 10)


ID      True Calc   False Calc              
Box1    7.5         25              
Box2    17.5        10
```

**Doing**

```
df_False=df[df["READY"] != TRUE]  
df_True=df[df["READY"] == TRUE]  

df_False['False Calc'] = df_False(SUM['USED'] * 10)
df_True['True Calc'] = df_True(SUM['USED'] * 0.5 + ('USED' * 1))
```

Is there a more simple approach to this question? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using groupby + apply, you can apply different formula based on the "ready" column values.

I do not understand your formula but here is an example :

```
 df.groupby(['ID', "ready"])["Used"].apply(lambda x : x.sum() * 1.5 if x.name[1] == True else x.sum() *10).unstack()
```

The result is the following :

```
ID,False,True
Box1,400.0,7.5
Box2,100.0,37.5
```

Comment: Ok is there a way to turn this output into a dataframe?

Comment: Actually this output is already a dataframe !